# Error: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm adding a new item to a form, however when I do it is giving the error message in the logs

> CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: "An
> exception occurred while executing 'SELECT p0_.name AS name0,
> p0_.projectId AS projectId1 FROM Project p0_ WITH (NOLOCK) ORDER BY
> p0_.projectId ASC':  SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native
> Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Project'.

The entity is defined so I'm not sure why I'm getting that error message.

This is what I have to add the new item

```
->add('project', 'entity', [
    'label' => 'Project',
    'class' => 'comtwclagripayrollBundle:Project',
    'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('pr')
                    ->orderBy('pr.projectId');       
            }  
        ]
    )
```

Comment: I would check permissions. If the account that this is using doesn't have permission on the table/view, Sql Server might throw such an exception

Comment: I think I need to clear the cache but I don't remember how to do it from the console window.

Comment: `bin/console cache:clear` clears the cache.

Comment: I don't remember how to find the console window to execute that.

Comment: Are you sure your database is in sync with your entities? Did you check `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`?

Comment: I did that but it still not working